# Prevent tactical downvoting at the end of the bounty auto-award period?

Tags: feature-request, bounty, tactical-downvoting

Example of bounty on question:

---

## Example

**Question:** This is my problem? **(has bounty of +250)**

**Answer:** 4 answers (no any answer accepted)

1. 3 Votes - *(first answer by date)* **(answered by me)**
2. 3 Votes - *(second answer by date)*
3. 2 Votes - *(fourth answer by date)*
4. 0 Votes - *(third answer by date)*

---

## Bounty Rules

I would like to highlight some rules from current SO bounty guide line https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty,

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

---

## Scenario

Explaining my question's scenario,

- Yes grace period is over and bounty creator has not awarded any one answer
- Two answers have same highest vote and has more than 2 score
- It will tied in question (1) and (2) and half bounty award goes to (1) answer means my answer because its oldest answer.

---

## Concern

In last moment of grace period is going to over, If (2) answer owner will down vote (1) answer means my answer then the half bounty award goes to (2) answer.

We don't know that (2) answer owner's intention, they think that my answer is not useful, or they want to bounty award points.

---

## Opinion

There should some rules against this kind of problems, I am just suggesting,

- in grace period, any of the answers owner will not be able to vote on any of the other answers

Comment: No. Anyone is free to downvote and you should not assume such situation. You may get a downvote that will not make you earn the bounty and you have no way to know who downvoted you and why. Simply consider that *someone found your answer not useful*

Comment: also your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62721755/8620333 smells *product promotion only* (you are basically copying the github content)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, You are right, i have no rights to assume such situation, but if i do this with another person then? but we can say system has rights to put some rules and assume such situation.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, that answer described the question requirement step by step explanation with features, its not product promotion, that is i have created and my first time GitHub project.

Comment: Assume no malice. One should vote based on quality. Do not assume the identity of a vote. Votes are personal. You can find a lot of upvoted answers with quality that justify downvotes. Imagine an answer with a lot of security flaw, or ignore half of the requirement, or pretend to solve the issue, or do not address edge case. Those are plenty of valid reason to downvote. Peoples may not fully review existing answers before writting one. Why would writing an answer invalid your review of existing answers? Note that I'm not talking about any of your answer, but the general Feature request

Comment: @RobertLongson can you explain which content copied from another site? if you talk about this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62721755/8987128 answer is purely created by me and that GitHub repo is own by me, you have no rights to talk discuss another questions here.

Comment: we *all* have the rights to discuss any question/answer here. This is why it's called a community

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes but if its related to this question, and and its not fare to blame another person without knowing him and related things with him, i respect you all and community.

Comment: Note that the Title and the actual Feature Request is confusing. "_How to avoid criticism on my answer when_", no matter when feedback are a feature. No process should block feed back except deletion.

Comment: @DragandDrop thanks, i appreciate your thoughts in previous comment.

Comment: Sorry I only later noticed it is your content, that makes it product promotion as a previous commenter has mentioned.

Comment: @RobertLongson, its ok, we have to check that question purpose and what he want, he has mention features in bounty, I have created that library for that particular question for learning purpose, and i have just explained and compared features with requirement library and then after i have updated my first GitHub Repo, and also have referred other libraries too them in same answer,  If its promotion then why Stack Overflow Community and question owner never raised concern regarding this.

Comment: The bonus giver loses all of the bonus whether or not any or part of it is awarded. Their voting does not affect that. They can award the bounty to whomever they want. They also have the right to vote on every post. So what is the problem? Your question does not clearly explain & justify a problem that incorporates those relevant facts.

Comment: @Philipxy thanks for reply, have mentioned in question, you can check in concern and opinion. and i agree with the comment of @@DragandDrop..

Comment: Your concern is that the owner might vote on answers during the grace period so that the bounty would get auto awarded to another answer instead of directly awarding that answer the bounty?

Comment: @JoeW, if 2 answers scores are same and there is one answer by me, and question owner will not award any of the answer, then automatically oldest answer will awarded but the concern is if before grace period over i down vote competitor answer for my benefit or he down vote my answer for his benefit then there is a problem.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, I can barely understand your question, and you haven't addressed the problems my comment. If anyone wants to vote some ways and/or the bonus offerer awards the bounty by hand or not, that's their choices. There is no problem. PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: meh, the points don't matter anyway, what's the big deal

Comment: @kevinB you mean the bounty feature is not motivating us? if its not important then SO will not give us this feature.

Comment: The bounty feature exists because without it people would resort to... harder to deal with ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: @KevinB yes you are absolutely right, we can think this way also.

Answer (score 11):

While there is *some* potential to abuse from tactical-downvoting on bounties, and one could argue that the competing answers owners are only temporarily prevented from voting (they can vote before and after the grace period after all), in the end very little would be achieved: users intent on gaming the auto-award would simply vote vote **before** the grace period starts.

Yup, you would catch out those users that were unaware of this feature, but that's all.

I don't see anything particularly harmful in the proposal, but I also see extremely marginal and entirely circumstantial gains. Unawarded bounties are not really awesome examples of the model working after all.

Not exactly the most exciting fish to be fishing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  you are right one major factor is un-awarded bounties are not really awesome examples of the model.