# Flag on comment declined every time

Tags: support, comment-flags

Someone commented on my [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399447/prevent-tactical-downvoting-at-the-end-of-the-bounty-auto-award-period#comment782816_399447) and that comment is not related with current question, I have flagged many time but its declined every time,

It's okay if comment is not part of the answer but other viewers are looking at that comment first and predict something related to comment and that comment mentioned my another question's answer.

Am I doing wrong in flagging the comment? If I am wrong then moderator should give some description on decline?

I already looked this posts [Why was this comment flag declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338547/why-was-this-comment-flag-declined)

Edited:

- Flagged type: "unfriendly or unkind"
- Flagged type: "Something else" and my comment was "Have mentioned my personal things and just predicted, its affecting another visitors and this is not related with this question, please try to understand and check the purpose"

Comment: You are asking a question on meta about a bounty that your probably answered so well, I/we have to checkout your answers to see this. You put the light on you so you need to accept that people will check things around you and I am not saying anything bad on that comment. It's was a simple deduction based on the content of your answer. i am not violating any code of conduct doing this.

Comment: by the way, I have discovered an answer there doing plagiarism that I have flagged and now it's deleted thanks to your meta question. This is called the meta effect.

Comment: turivishal, Just making sure you intend to bring more attention to your unresearched feature-request... Why? You already got plenty of votes... and there are plenty of duplicates about "don't allow votes on the question where you have an answer"... Or maybe you wanted to get more "not an answer" comments on the answer linked for *the comment*? I don't understand why people try to do so - it's is just waste of "meta effect' - one could improve they posts first and then shine meta light... but  it is rarely done in that order...

Comment: @TemaniAfif are talking double way, look at your first comment here and below answer comment, if its plagiarism then why are you abusing me in another question? you can comment there down vote there raise the concern there..

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov its not unrehearsed feature-request question and look at the answer on that question some one approving that kind of activity and problem..sorry i am not debating here, look at my profile and my progress, first time i felt its totally abuse to mention personal things..

Comment: @turivishal what "personal things" you are talking about? Link to a publicly available post you've authored under CC license - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62439725/css-javascript-slide-animation-without-jquery-something-similar-to-jquery-cyc/62721755#62721755 ? Calling that "personal thing" is a stretch... The fact that that answer does not meet SO requirement for an answer is pretty clear and hard to argue with - feel free to ask with "specific-question" tag about it if you disagree... (Indeed I could be totally wrong about "the comment"... )

Comment: @alexeiLevenkov yes we can say its person means from my profile, because that answer just picking from my profile and mention in another question its not proper, anyone can debate there particular answer and that is not my personal.. anyone can raise concern in same answer its copy of github and product promotion but no one can mention in another question because its not related to question.

Comment: @turivishal mentioning that particular answer was very proper in the feature request you made - as I commented earlier FR requires some justification in form "that happens often" - since there is no known evidence for "tactical downvote for bounties" the question that was linked is the only likely cause for feature to be requested/accepted. Pointing out that it is unlikely the case of "tactical downvote" decrease base for FR from 1 to 0 cases - so *very* relevant to that particular FR.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes you are right, i respect you, again i am ok with that question but my concern is if he has mention "looks like you bla bla answer is copy of code and looking like product promotion thats why tactical downvote for bounties" thats called manner, but if he say direct "it is copy of code and product promotion" not i am but anyone can feel abuse on this type of comment.

Comment: You should ask separate question whether your answer is acceptable for SO or not.

Answer (score 28):

Yes, there is no point in continuing to flag the comment for exactly the same reason when your flag was already declined once.

You flagged those same two comments a grand total of 10 times, 7 times on a *single* comment. I was growing very tired of it. I'm glad you finally realized it was futile.

The comment *is* related: your question was raising a concern about tactical downvoting on questions with bounties. There's an implicit assumption being made there that the downvotes were inappropriate or undeserved. The comment was pointing out an alternative explanation for why your answer may have been downvoted, one that doesn't require any tactical downvoting and isn't related to the bounty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry for my continues flag, I don't know why you still thinking that comment relates with my question, its ok if he pointed that my answer on that comment but, if he says its product promotion then that was not my intention and that words are not related with question, do you think its related with question?

Comment: @turivishal - It wasn't said that *it is* product promotion. That comment pointed how how it may look. That's a big difference.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, I appreciate his first comment i am satisfied, but in second comment some words "you are basically copying the github content", this is totally blame, if i am copying then he has to comment on that answer, why he is mentioning here.

Comment: Is there really much of a difference saying "this looks like it could potentially be related to malice" and "this is related to malice"? They both level the same charge, as they both require the same amount of work to verify, being that a sound minded individual would need to see for themselves if that is indeed the case and will set out upon finding out with the mindset of looking for malice.

Comment: There is no relationship between product promotion and someone referring to a specific answer of *yours* with which they have no affiliation.

Comment: @CodyGray - I mean, unless someone referring to that specific answer *specifically* states that the answer is probably product promotion, right? That is the link we are talking about here. The overall issue is, is it fair to accuse someone of product placement for simply making a github project to support their answer?

Comment: @TravisJ I am not accusing anyone. The OP made a project based on the question but the answer seems basically *checkout my project on github and help me improve it*. Also the content of the answer is a copy/past of the github. I think the answer can be written a bit differently to answer the question and at the end link to the github project for more details. By the way, the whole question is off-topic IMO. It's too broad and can even fall into *suggest external ressources*

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Of course you didn't *directly* accuse him, you just strongly asserted the possibility. As for if the question is off topic, please consider contributing to the discussion to [Make it easier to close job shop “gimme teh codez” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308837/1026459)

Comment: @CodyGray Its you opinion, you aresaying no relationship between product promotion and someone referring to a specific answer, its what i saying its not related with that question and not meaning anything..

Comment: @TemaniAfif still you are saying, that particular answer was copy of github then why are you  not talking there particular answer? why to mention here? If my question is board then ok i am accepting but there is no logic to mention other answer's problem to abuse some one.

Comment: @CodyGray i respect you and community please look at the proper concern i am still no satisfied..

Comment: @TravisJ thanks for you understanding, hope at least one person can understand this kind of concern.

Comment: @turivishal we (frequent visitors of meta) are generally awful - we pay attention to what people say and try to make sure they don't use bad or misguided starting points for they questions. It is super rare for person to come to meta for first time and suggest something that totally not related to they experiences. It is generally expected that when one suggest feature to disable something - downvotes in your case - that the person considers some usage of the feature hurting them intentionally even if they misinterpret the the cause....

Comment: ... For some reason you seem to believe that the fact one actually decided to make sure you are not misinterpreting events of a most likely case (which your question basically pinpoints to exact on - bounties are not that common) is a personal attack. It is unfortunate that you treat it that way but it is very unlikely it was intended that way. Also feature request require some example cases and that comment essentially ruled out the only case you had to support the need of the feature which is very  relevant to the feature's fate.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for reply, i understand someone intention is not hurting, its ok i am taking my step back, if everyone wants then i am accepting its my fault, and you are right its ok some one can point abuse things "copy code", "product promotion" that related to person.

Comment: @turivishal it would be *soo much easier* to fix your answer so it actually *answers the question* inline in the answer and does not consist of copy of your github page with list of features of your library - there is absolutely nothing right now in that answer that is not "product promotion". I don't get why you consider that "abuse". Content of that answer is not suitable for SO answer - we do appreciate you working a lot to solve the problem but answer must be answer...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thats why i am not satisfied, and because its not related,and that answer i got auto bounty award, and its not related and not an example to this question, that answer was totally created by me first and that bounty owner mentioned required things in bounty description and i have just explained comparison of requirement.. first i described in SO and then after i created my repo because of time limit.

Comment: Can you please stop raising flags on that comment? I cannot possibly make it any more clear...

Comment: @CodyGray its ok i am taking my step back, i respect you, because you all are the reputed and experienced, i thought anyone can understand but its ok, i never read in SO guideline if i abuse or hurt by anyone then that i have to agree and keep tolerate.